# Visual studio Outlook Plugin getting system.data.SQLite.dll has a different computed hash than specified in manifest

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, clickonce, office-addins

we have created outlook plugin based project in Visual studio, when we installing plugin with OutlookAddin.vsto file while we are getting an error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> system.data.SQLite.dll has a different computed hash than specified in manifest

The reason for this problem is the file "system.data.SQLite.dll" get the new hash after you re-sign your executable, this cause "system.data.SQLite.dll" have a different hash than specified in the manifest.

To resolve this problem, you need to update or regenerate the application manifest using [mage.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acz3y3te.aspx).

You can also try below solution where you could sign the executable in the `AfterCompile` target. You can use the following element before the final project close tag (see your project's content).

```
<Target Name="AfterCompile" Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
  <Exec Command="&quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Bin\signtool.exe&quot; sign /f &quot;C:\temp\myPFX.pfx&quot; /p &quot;admin&quot; /v &quot;$(ProjectDir)obj\$(ConfigurationName)\$(TargetFileName)&quot;" />
</Target>
```

Read more about that in the [Windows 8 and ClickOnce : the definitive answer revisited](https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2013/04/14/windows-8-and-clickonce-the-definitive-answer-revisited/) article.